# How to choose metrics in Apache Kafka for fitting service time distribution?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, metrics, data-fitting, jconsole

I want to study the distribution of the service time in Kafka. Actually, it's the service time that a broker deals with each request. I found the `TotalTimeMs` and `RequesQueuetTimeMs` from the documentation (https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html). I also used `jconsole` to view the metrics provided by Kafka, but since I want to do a fitting of the time metrics, how can I get the full logs of the metrics of every requests? Or do I need to write a program myself to get what I need?

Comment: What do you consider a request? Producing messages or Consuming messages?

Comment: According to the documentation there are three types of requests: Produce, FetchConsumer and FetchFollower, here I only consider Produce request. You may also refer to this instruction here (https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kafka-performance-metrics/) where it introduce what TotalTimeMs means

Comment: Those are server-side broker metrics. FetchConsumer is a server-side consumer metric. I think what you want (metrics per message Produced) is not easy to do because the producer will batch message and there are no metrics at this level of granularity. The only way I can imagine is if you instrument your Producer code. You also need to define what you want to measure. Since your batch is sent and the ackowneldge callback is received? Are You sure you cant rely on [Producer metrics](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#producer-metrics) which has rate/max/mean for your study?

Comment: I think what you want can be accomplished by Tracing, in general. Look into OpenTracing and/or Zipkin